# How to select clients which made minimum 2 transactions during last 30 days from current date in Terada SQL?

Tags: sql, date, teradata, teradata-sql-assistant, teradatasql

I have table in Teradata SQL about transactions like below:

```
ID   | NAME | DATE
------------
123  | Adam | 10-09-2021
123  | Adam | 11-09-2021
333  | Jane | 15-06-2021
456  | Tom  | 11-02-2016
123  | Adam | 08-09-2021
333  | Jane | 22-01-2021
123  | Adam | 23-05-2017
```

- ID - id of client
- NAME - name of client
- DATE - date of transaction

And I would like to select only these clients who made minimum 2 transactions during last 30 days from today date (13-09-2021).

So as a result I need something like below, because only client Adam made MINIMUM 2 transactions during last 40 days from current date.

```
ID   | NAME
------------
123  | Adam
```

How can I do that in Teradata SQL ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmmm . . . if you only want the clients, then this is filtering and aggregation:

```
select id, name
from transactions
where date >= current_date - 30
group by id, name
having count(*) >= 2;
```